# How to render body element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas to take a snapshot of my webpage and paste it somewhere in my server.
I am trying to Render the body element and restrict canvas size to 300x300px
This is the code that is doing to trick

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  },
  width: 300,
  height: 300
});
```

And this is the [website](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html) where the demo is available.

My problem is that I am new to html2canvas and I couldn't figure out how to paste this code and use it on my local file.
I would really appreciate it if someone can give me steps or explain for me where and how to use this code to make it screenshot my local webpage.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid but I do not really understand what you want to do.
The above code should already take a screenshot of your webpage. You just have to include the html2canvas.js and paste the code in your main JavaScript file or your documents head.

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script>
        html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            },
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        });       
     </script>
</head>
```

Saving that image to your server is a little tricky. 
HTML2Canvas renders the image via the [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).
That means, an image file is created during the runtime and then written to the canvas (via [drawImage()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp)).

To get that data back, you may call the [toDataURL() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975241(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var imageData = canvas.toDataURL();
    },
    width:300,
    height:300
});
```

In my case, that imageData variable contains something like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA...`.
That's an base64 encoded string of the image data with mime-type image/png.
To save that image to your server, you need something that is able to write to the server. Since JavaScript runs clientside (in your browser), it's not allowed to do so.
You could send that data to a PHP file using an AJAX call:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var imageData = canvas.toDataURL(),
            request = new XMLHTTPRequest() || new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        request.open("POST","saveImage.php",true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","image/png");
        request.send("imageData=" + imageData);

    },
    width:300,
    height:300
});
```

The content of that PHP file may look like the following:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] !== "POST") die;

$fp = fopen("path/to/image/folder/" . time() . ".png","w");
fwrite($fp,base64_decode($_POST["imageData"]));
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Actually, that's the way I would do it. But the code is untested. If you have any questions, please feel free to ask!

EDIT:
Not sure if the content-type of image/png is correct or if it has to be transferred as text/plain or something like that.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. I have done everything as you have explained but if I wanted to download the screenshot instead of displaying it on the webpage how can I do that ?

Comment: You could create an image instead of the Canvas:

    `var imageData = canvas.toDataURL(),
        image = new Image();
    image.src = imageData;
    document.body.appendChild(image);`

This will display a "normal" image instead of the canvas which you can download via rightclick -> save...